# String search wont print full line

Tags: c, linux

So basically what im trying to do is something similar to grep for instance.

> ./a.out file string

Here is my code

```
fp = fopen(file, "r");

while(fgets(buffer, 200, fp) != NULL )
{   
    line++; //Add new line
    if(strstr(pattern, buffer) != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(data, "%s", buffer); //So we can tell if the file is clean
        printf("Wow what do we have here?\n Data:%s\nLine:%d\n", data, line);
    }
    else if(data == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Looks like you are clean :/ or maybe i just suck\n");
    }
}
```

Now this will find the string but it has to be at the start of the line, for example

> cat example.txt
>
> line #This would be found

My aim is to make it find the string in the line and print the full line

Comment: `strstr(pattern, buffer)` --> `strstr(buffer, pattern)`

Comment: Also `data == NULL` might never become true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of strstr function is:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

The 'pattern' you want to find should be your second argument and 'buffer' should be your first argument.

P.S. Referring to the man pages is a very important habit to cultivate.